# Laravel validation unique subcatetory with diferent category

Tags: laravel, validation, unique

I want to determine the field unique in **laravel** with the follow code:

This is the validation to the table `product_subcategories`:

```php
protected $rules = [
    ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE => [
        'name'                  => 'required|unique:product_subcategories|max:255',
        'product_categories_id' => 'required'
    ],
    ValidatorInterface::RULE_UPDATE => [
        'id'                    => 'required',
        'name'                  => 'required|unique:product_subcategories|max:255',
        'product_categories_id' => 'required'
    ]
];
```

But I want that the field name be unique with the `product_categories_id`, for example, it cant be unique if the name of the field is the same but with `product_categories_id` is different each other. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the column to compare to with the second parameter of the rule.

```php
protected $rules = [
    ValidatorInterface::RULE_CREATE => [
        'name'                  => 'required|unique:product_subcategories,name|max:255',
        'product_categories_id' => 'required'
    ],
    ValidatorInterface::RULE_UPDATE => [
        'id'                    => 'required',
        'name'                  => 'required|unique:product_subcategories,name|max:255',
        'product_categories_id' => 'required'
    ]
]
```

This example will be checking if there is any other field in `product_subcategories` with the same `name`.

For update, you can extend this with a third parameter which is the value of the name you want to ignore. (So you can save the SubCategory without changing it's name.)